# Specifying Error type for the Result returned (in the context of SinkExt.with)

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to use **SinkExt.with** to transform packet bytes, before sending. This a minimal code snippet:

```rust
let (mut sink, stream) = codec::Framed::new(serial, codec::ProtocolCodec::new()).split();

let sink = sink.with(|input: Bytes| {
    // transform input
    future::ready(Ok(input))
});
```

Unfortunately, the compiler (1.39.0) complains:

```
error[E0698]: type inside `async` object must be known in this context
  --> src/main.rs:68:25
   |
68 |         let sink = sink.with(|b: Bytes| {
   |                         ^^^^ cannot infer type for `E`
   |
```

I can understand, that it lacks the type of a possible error (E) for the **Result** I'm returning. My problem is that I cannot understand how to properly specify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the turbofish to explicitly specify types:

`sink.with::<_,_,_/*E*/MyCustomErrorTypeOrSomethingSimilar>(|b: Bytes| {...})`.